# Is it possible to draw two custom info windows for each marker in OSMDroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Is it possible to draw two info windows for each marker in OSMdroid?

Here is how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: Only one **InfoWindow** object per **OverlayWithIW** derived object is supported by OsmDroid (which include **Marker, Polygon, Polyline,** etc, that require **InfoWindow**). If you want something similar to the above design, extend any **Overlay**-based or **InfoWindow** class and override its canvas drawing methods. https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/dbb20901cac30b28a6a9349da097c22d9a962311/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/OverlayWithIW.java

Comment: You can do something like this [BasicInfoWindow](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/dbb20901cac30b28a6a9349da097c22d9a962311/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/infowindow/BasicInfoWindow.java) or [MarkerInfoWindow](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/dbb20901cac30b28a6a9349da097c22d9a962311/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/infowindow/MarkerInfoWindow.java)

Comment: Sample points https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/dbb20901cac30b28a6a9349da097c22d9a962311/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/data/SampleSimpleFastPointOverlay.java This sample demo can be found under ***More Samples > Data > Simple Fast Point Overlay with 60k points*** in OsmDroid demo app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.osmdroid

Comment: @ecle thanks a lot for your ideas. I will learn all of it and reply